# sql Query to select three of each referenced id

Tags: c#, html, sql, database

I'm using a `SqlDataSource` to bring back data to be displayed in a drop down. The headers of each drop down is the brand and in the drop down I want three products of each brand to be brought back.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Categories" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Categories %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM CATEGORY WHERE CategoryID <5"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="Categories">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <ul>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="images" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Categories %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM ITEM ORDER BY Category_ref"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <li id="<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>">
    <a href="<%# Eval("CategoryName", "{0}.aspx") %>"><%# Eval("CategoryName") %></a>
    <div class="dropDown">
        <div class="listItem">
        <asp:ListView ID="listview3" runat="server" DataSourceID="images">
            <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ItemID","Product.aspx?id={0}") %>'>
                <p class="<%# Eval("Category_ref", "brand{0}") %>">
                <asp:Image ID="image" CssClass="dropImg" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PhotoPath", "images/products/{0}") %>' />
                <br />
                <span><%# Eval("ItemName") %></span>

                <%# Eval("ItemID").ToString() %>
                </p>
            </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

That is my entire navigation with the brand names coming back from database as well as the product information.

The second `SqlDataSource` query is where I need to fix up so it only selects 3 product. If there is a fourth it will leave it out.

Comment: Your `<ul>` in the `<LayoutTemplate>` isn't closed...

Comment: It closes a bit after the end of the closing listview because i add another header which doesnt ever change. I just didnt copy that bit in here @marc_s

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM ITEM ORDER BY Category_ref
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM ITEM ORDER BY Category_ref LIMIT 3
```

You should always specify your database of choice with your question, and reduce the problem to the essence (all that ASP code is irrelevant and just scares people from your question).

Comment: Good point. I thought it might but previous questions I've asked i havent had enough code. 
The top code worked so im using SQL Server. But it didnt get the results i wanted. If i do that it only gets the first 3 products. I want 3 products for each category. @Niels

Comment: That was another bug in your original code already. Add a `WHERE` clause factoring in the currently selected Category's ID.

Comment: As in when I hover the header it dynamically changes the select query?
How would I get that to work